# Phil Sturgeon’s REST API always returning: status:0, error:Unknown method

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, codeigniter-restserver

I am always getting the this error.

```
        {"status":false,"error":"Unknown method."}
```

But all syntax are correct from my side. because everything is working fine on the browser but same URL integration on the devices gives the 'unknown method error'.

I am using this 'get' method. Sample URL

```
       SITEURL/api/login/test?req_type=custom
```

Am I missing something while integrating? Perhaps a setting? I have just included the library and rest config file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to check that from device which method your are getting means they are sending 'POST' or 'GET' so you can update your function name accordingly.

In my case  I have done the function name as _get to the methods but from device methods of sending parameter is 'POST' which I am trying to access as 'GET'.

So please cross check this once.

Answer (score 4):

I think your problem is the name of controller is the same with the name of method try to make a test:

if the name of your controller is:

```
class Test extends REST_Controller{
    //your method name is different from the name of controller class
    public function testget_get(){ 
        echo $this->response(array('test'=> 'test'), 200);
    }
}
```

I have experienced this problem on hmvc structure.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a method with the library, you need to append the type of request you are going to make to it.

So, if your method is `test`, and you are making a `GET` request to it, it needs to look like this:

```
function test_get(){
    ...
}
```

Same with `POST` requests

```
function test_post(){
    ...
}
```

Same with `PUT`, and `DELETE` as well.

NB This is only a guess since you didn't include any of your code for some reason.

Comment: Thank you.. My issue is solved. actually I have done the correct like _get to the methods but from devices methods types are coming as 'post' which I am treating them as 'get'.